# Get IIS 7 worker process number given a PID

Tags: windows-server-2012, performance-monitor, iis-8

I am trying to add performance counters for an IIS worker process to a collection data set in Performance Monitor.

I know the process ID (PID) of the worker process (a 4 digit number). However, in the configuration of a data collection set, IIS worker processes are listed as numbers from 1 through the number of configured worker processes. They're in the format w3wp#1, w3wp#2, w3wp#3, etc.

So as an example, if the PID I'm interested in is 3865, how would I figure out what w3wp# it is in Performance Monitor?

Comment: i think you have to enable it backend in the registry to show the process id https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2010/03/29/perfmon-identifying-processes-by-pid-instead-of-instance/

Comment: but if i were you i would use perfmon instead so you dont have to touch the registry, but it seems this registry change is common

Comment: Thanks Michael. The registry change looks promising - seems like that is the exact problem. What I don't understand is your comment "I would use perfmon instead"? I am using perfmon and that's the problem: perfmon lists the arbitrary instance number as opposed to the PID. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: i mean an outside tool sysinternals (which Microsoft owns now) , I believe is a better tool for the job IMO and no registry tweaks would have been needed.  I will post the solution as an answer

Comment: Ok, I think I'm following. I guess I assumed that the management application known as Performance Monitor and the exe perfmon.exe were one in the same - but apparently not? I'll check it out. The other thing is that I am looking to turn on logging that will run for days and collect data. Not sure if this other application supports that. But again, I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: no problem,  but if i answered your question please mark it if it was correct if so..............thanks................

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have to edit the registry to expose this (be careful)

Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance

1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\PerfProc\Performance
3. On the Edit menu, click New, and then click DWORD Value.
4. Right-click New Value #1, click Rename, and then type ProcessNameFormat to name the new value
5. Right-click ProcessNameFormat, and then click Modify.
6. In the Data value box, type one of the following values, and then click OK:
7. 1: Disables PID data. This value is the default value.
8. 2: Enables PID data.
9. Exit Registry Editor.

This solves the problem that you had where They're in the format w3wp#1, w3wp#2, w3wp#3

and now will be in the format

They will now have the PID in the format like so w3wp3865, w3wp2325, w3wp2154

and you can add a performance counter for what your looking for explicitly as you asked w3wp3865

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2010/03/29/perfmon-identifying-processes-by-pid-instead-of-instance/

As an alternative, sysinternals perfmon.exe should be able to get performance information (if not more) without altering the registry.  But I am not sure If its the exact details you need.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how this answers the question?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

One of of the Process' counters is the process id. Use that counter to relate your process to the w3wp#N. Note that this can change from sample to sample when e.g. a process dies or is started. Better to follow the instructions about setting ProcessNameFormat=2.